# Importing Angular library into Lotus Domino db

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm experimenting with using Angular and so am looking to import the standard library angular.min.js into a Domino database with Domino designer.

However when I do this, I get zillions of javascript errors in the imported file.
I have tried:

- Pasting in as a javascript script library
- Importing directly as a Resource file
- Importing as WebContent via Package Explorer.

The version of angular.min.js I am using is straight from the Angular website, and works just fine if included in a locally run html file.

The symptoms are that firstly including the file doesn't work (generates script errors in browser) and if I look at the resource / script lib etc I see loads of red markers for syntax errors.

The odd part is that the same method(s) to include jquery seem to work fine.

Has anyone else managed this?  Surely they must have.. I bet I'm doing something impressivley stupid

In case it's relevant, this is eventually for use in an xpage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First: forget about opening the Angular JS file in Designer. It will throw errors because it uses JavaScript syntax that isn't supported by the built-in editor. The file is (probably) just fine.

Next, I'm not sure where you're loading the file exactly, but if you want to do it in an XPage: here's a simple example I just created and that works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.attrs>
      <xp:attr
        name="ng-app"
        value="myApp">
     </xp:attr>
    </xp:this.attrs>

<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:script
        src="angular/angular.min.js"
        clientSide="true">
    </xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>

<div ng-controller="MyController">
    {{hello}} this
</div>

<xp:scriptBlock
    id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  $scope.hello = 'world';

});
]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>

</xp:view>
```

Comment: "Just ignore the errors" seems so counter-intuitive ! But you're right, forget about viewing it in eclipse, just include the file in the xpage anyway and it worked fine. My previous example (which prompted me to ask the question) was including the file wrongly. Thanks for the info !

Comment: Mark's spot on, but I recommend (since I don't looking at errors in my apps, and I don't need DDE to attempt to parse my minified, production Angular library) keeping the _angular.min.js_ file in your _WebContent_ path (view via Package Explorer or Navigator) inside a directory like _js_ or _lib_.

Comment: Absolutely. Should have added that to my answer. The issue remains though: if you open it from there with Designer, it still shows errors on the built-in editor. But to be fair: most JavaScript libraries do.

Comment: @EricMcCormick and Mark - yes I found the same thing. That was my last attempt before asking this question (ie still got the errors). For others coming up against this, it's useful info to have written here.

Comment: What I was getting at is that you can just paste it in there and not need to open it ever. If DDE doesn't open/process it, how can it mistakenly show it as having errors? (This is what I do for my local copy of minimized JS libs.)

Answer (score 4):

Here are some interesting links for starting with **angular** and **domino**:

http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1458

http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1485

http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1525

http://hasselba.ch/blog/?cat=50

http://xomino.com/2014/06/01/angular-js-in-xpages-6-a-people-manager-crud-application/

I hope this helps...

Comment: hi  - these links didn't answer the question (ie still had trouble importing the angular.min.js file) but this is really useful info, so thank you !!